# Jssor - Creating Margins with Full Width Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, jssor

I am using the 'Full Width Slider' only I don't want it to be full width, I want it to be full width inside a div that takes up about 80% of the page. I had trouble adjusting the width of the slider1_container (if I deceased the number it would increase in size for example). So I decided to create my own div and let it sit within this. The problem is that when I setup the css styles for my own div with margin-left: 10px; or margin-left: 10%; it pushes the slideshow into the side (either by 10px or 10%) which will generate a scroll bar, no matter how big my page is. I want the container (which can be my container) to take up 80% of the page with a 10% margin each side. Margin-right seems to do nothing to my container with the slideshow, either.

Updated with my code:

```
 //responsive code begin
 //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
 function ScaleSlider() {
var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
if (parentWidth) {
    var sliderWidth = parentWidth;

    //keep the slider width no more than 800
    sliderWidth = Math.min(sliderWidth, 1200);

    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(sliderWidth);
}
else
    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
 }
 ScaleSlider();

 $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
 $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
    };
</script>


 <div class="left-slide-container">

<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1200px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">



<!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1200px;
        height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-slide-container {
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right. Please use the following code to fit jssor slider in your container.

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth) {
        var sliderWidth = parentWidth;

        //keep the slider width no more than 800
        sliderWidth = Math.min(sliderWidth, 800);

        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(sliderWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

Comment: Thank you. It now won't scale though (i.e. responsive). Perhaps my width for "slider1_container" an "slides" needs to be a percentage, too? It doesn't seem to like that though..